# Class design - ctor or properties with public setter

Tags: c#, .net

Pretty simple question, say I have a class with 20 **reference type properties** that *I know* will only be set at class creation/immediately after class is created and where none of the properties are really mandatory.

In this scenario, would best practice be to create a `ctor` accepting 20 properties (which, since they are all reference types, would still allow you to pass `null` if you wanted to) and to ensure none of my properties have a `setter`

or ...

To simply not have a `ctor` at all and just provide a `setter` for all of my properties?

I am leaning towards the latter because of ease of implementation and (arguably) cleaner code even though that doesn't guarantee object immutability, but again these classes are only used internally and I know that I won't be changing them anyway.

**EDIT**

If you're going to vote to close the question, at least have the decency of explaining why you think the question is not "good enough" for the ohh-so-high SO standards.

If this is not a question that belongs here, I really don't know what SO is for anymore.

Comment: have you seen a constructor with 20 parameters before? for the life of me i cant remember seeing one. it doesn't really make sense, and seems like its the wrong approach.

Comment: @TheGeneral are you arguing that because I have never seen one before no valid reason can ever be concocted to justify having one?

Comment: It really depends. Are the parameters semantically related? If so, you might want to have your object `Foo` expose a constructor that accepts a `FooSettings` object, which contains these values. If not, and the object is valid without them, keep them as properties, e.g. like UI controls normally do. In any case, a 20 parameter constructor is a great way to make sure no one wants to use your object.

Comment: Passing nullz around is rarely a good idea. You might want to consider grouping these properties in other classes or structs...

Comment: Imagine usage of constructor with 20 default params..and you want to set last parameters only - you will have to pass 19 nulls to set only one param - ugly as hell. So pass FooSettings as @Rotem suggests if you want to go for constructor option.

Comment: @TheGeneral I see this kind of constructor quite often. Complex requirements tend to lead to complex code. However I agree it´s allmost allways a code-smell.

Comment: @HimBromBeere even in DI world this would beg to be refactored. having that many parameters would be failing my code reviews (said subjectively in the spirit of the question)

Comment: _"I see this kind of constructor quite often"_ - me too. You end out with a Parameters class that has 20 mutable properties with are set with a collection initializer, which then gets passed to the original method. Now no-one 'knows' your contructor takes 20 arguments.

Comment: which only hides away complexity, in particular if that param-class has such a meaningul name as `ParamClass`:) But that´s another topic.

Comment: I actually think there is more complexity (at least visually) at guessing at 20 parameters or having to insert 15 nulls to use 5 . Anyway i vote for no

Comment: I agree with @TheGeneral, hence having said I am leaning towards the latter approach.

Comment: Did you see this similar question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3462/constructors-lots-of-paramters-or-none-and-use-of-set-methods?

Comment: @Reniuz - C# supports named arguments so you wouldn't necessarily need to pass the 19 nulls.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway that assumes that the ctor would be built entirely of optional params, which is a possibility, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all these properties aren't mandatory and they don't have to be readonly, you don't need a constructor. No one wants to call a constructor that takes 20 arguments, especially if they aren't necessary.

So even if this question tends to be subjective, use properties and omit the constructor.

Comment: While I agree with this, it does mean the object is not immutable without a ctor. Not that I would care much for immutability personally but loads of people would make arguments for ensuring your objects are immutable at all costs.

Comment: @cogumel0 if you want it immutable, then user a builder and pass it in

Comment: "So even if this question tends to be subjective" Don´t answer it but flag it as such.

Answer (score 0):

You should make them properties and use an object initializer:

```
class Cat
{
    // Auto-implemented properties.
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public object OtherProperty { get; set; }
}

Cat cat = new Cat { Age = 10, Name = "Fluffy" };
```

This gives you nice compact code, without having to specify the properties you don't need. Even if you do specify all the properties, it's not much longer.

I'd use a constructor where properties are mandatory, or based on some sort of source object like a DataRow or file.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like Single Responsibility Principle violation. It's recommended to have 0-3 parameters in method including constructor.

Comment: "It's recommended to have 0-3 parameters in method including constructor." Sais whom? Generelly making such generel statements is bad.

Comment: It's not about how many parameters a constructor has, but how many different things a class does.